# How to understand this unfamiliar casting?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    __int64 a = (__int64)"J\x10";
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, the result is `a = 12950320`.

How to understand `(__int64)"J\x10"`?

Comment: How much do you know about [*explicit type conversions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)? Especially C-style type-casts (which you should always see as a red flag of something wrong in the code)?

Comment: I got no errors and warnings

Comment: These type of casts are a way of telling the compiler to do something that it normally would flag as an error so you are unlikely to get an error or warning in such cases. Remove the `(__int64)` part and your compiler should complain.

Answer (score 2):

`"J\x10"` is a string literal. String literals are arrays of characters with static storage.

`__int64` is presumably some type. Based on the name, we can presume that it is some implementation defined (non-standard) <sup>1</sup> 64 bits wide signed integer type.

Expression `(T)expression` is an explicit type conversion colloquially called C-style cast. It performs one or combination of <sup>2</sup> static cast, reinterpret cast or const cast on the operand expression. In this case, the expression converts the value of the string literal expression into the type `__int64`.

When the value of an array (such as string literal) is used, it is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element. This is called decaying. The value of a pointer is the memory address where the object is stored.

So, this pointer to the first character of the string literal is converted to the implementation defined integer type. There is no static cast from pointer to integer, so this is a reinterpret cast. Assuming the integer type is large enough to represent the value stored in the pointer (that'll be the case for most systems today, but is not something guaranteed by C++), this conversion maps the address value to some integer value in an implementation defined manner.

If you're still confused: That's fine; the program doesn't make much sense even after understanding what it does.

---

<sup>1</sup> This means that using such type makes the program usable only on limited set of systems that support such special type.

<sup>2</sup> It is generally recommended to avoid using C-style casts and instead use one of the specific casts that you intend to use. C-style casts often prevent the compiler from catching obvious bugs. Also, reinterpret cast and const cast should not be used unless you know exactly what it does in the context where you use it and what are the ramifications.

Answer (score 0):

`"J\x10"` is a string (two chars here, "J" and hexa 10), which by default in C++ is considered as a `const char*`.

You are trying to cast that `const char *` to a `__int64` value and store it at "a". I think this is a nasty cast.

Running this code several times will shows you that the pointer may vary from to execution to execution (it may show as the same, just due to OS cache).

Another thing to take into account is that `__int64` is not a standard type, but a MS one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is an [explicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) as mentioned in comments. In this case is it relies heavily on programmer knowing what she/he is doing and memory space needed for the conversion.

Let's say we have memory of 2 bytes, and value of those 2 bytes are 0:

```
int16_t memory = 0; // 16 bits is 2 bytes, 
+-----------+-----------+
| 0000-0000 | 0000-0000 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Now we can read those 2 bytes individually (byte per byte), or collectivly (as whole 2 byte value). Now lets think of it as an `union`, and imagine that 2 byte memory space as independant spaces.

```cpp
union test{
    int16_t bytes2;
    int8_t  bytes[2];
    char    chars[2];
};
```

So when we input an value of 20299 into that union we can do next:

```cpp
union test sub;
sub.bytes2 = 20299;
std::cout << sub.bytes2 << std::endl;                                       // 20299
std::cout << (int)sub.bytes[1] << " " << (int)sub.bytes[0] << std::endl;    // 79 75
std::cout << sub.chars[1] << " " << sub.chars[0] << std::endl;              // O K
```

Which works like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|         20 299        |
+-----------+-----------+
|     79    |     75    |
+-----------+-----------+
|    'O'    |    'K'    |
+-----------+-----------+
```

But we could do the similar if we ignore several compiler warnings:

```cpp
sub.bytes2 = (int16_t)'OK';                                                 //CygWin will issue warning about this
std::cout << sub.bytes2 << std::endl;                                       // 20299
std::cout << (int)sub.bytes[1] << " " << (int)sub.bytes[0] << std::endl;    // 79 75
std::cout << sub.chars[1] << " " << sub.chars[0] << std::endl;              // O K
```

But if we pass an string `"OK"` instead of char array `'OK'` we will get an error **cast from 'const char*' to 'int16_t {aka short int}' loses precision [-fpermissive]**, and this is because `std::string` has an extra character *`\0`* that isn't shown marking an end of string. So instead of passing 2 byte constant, we are passing 3 byte constant, and our compiler is issuing an error.

Among memory error that I described earlier there is a lot more going on. Strings are pointers to the memory addres similar in functionality as our union. So any string is an reference to specific memory addres with no information how many bytes does that memory addres occupy (aka length of an string). Now there are headers ( `<string>` and `<cstring>` ) that help with that issue in many ways, but that is off topic for this question.

That is an pure basis how casting works, it reads 1 memory as a different type from original integer.

---

In code you provided we have `__int64 a = (__int64)"J\x10"` , where `__int64` in an [64 bit integer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/int8-int16-int32-int64?view=vs-2019) on Windows, and `"J\x10"` is string literal of specific size that holds value of those letters - but `\x10` is an integer of value of 16.

```
union test{
        uint64_t val;
        char chars[8];
    };
```

```cpp
int64_t a = (int64_t)"J\x10";
union test sub;
sub.val = a;
// 4299178052
std::cout << sub.val << std::endl;
// ◦ ◦ ◦  ◦ @ @ D
std::cout << sub.chars[7] << " "<< sub.chars[6] << " "<< sub.chars[5] << " "<< sub.chars[4] << " " << sub.chars[3] << " " << sub.chars[2] << " "<< sub.chars[1] << " "<< sub.chars[0] << " "<< std::endl;
// 0 0 0 1 0 40 40 44
std::cout <<std::hex << (int)sub.chars[7] << " "<<std::hex << (int)sub.chars[6] << " "<<std::hex << (int)sub.chars[5] << " "<<std::hex << (int)sub.chars[4] << " "<<std::hex << (int)sub.chars[3] << " " <<std::hex << (int)sub.chars[2] << " " <<std::hex << (int)sub.chars[1] << " "<<std::hex << (int)sub.chars[0] << " "<< std::endl;
```

But as you can see I didn't get the same result as you, and the issues range in more than this. `__int64` is an Virtual Studio only type only, and it is corresponding to the `long long`, how constant memory reads is prone to errors of referencing, and in general it is bad code that should be discouraged.

This kind of behaviour, especially with [VS type only](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/20603/) is not easy to understand, and it doesn't have to have same result, it can also raise numerous errors if copy/pasted that are hard to decipher if OS and IDE brands are unknown or not present in metadata. You should always use known [aliases and references](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/)